# Create a condition to check if array has value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a condition to check if all value in the array is 0. here's the example of the array.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "0"
  1 => "100"
  2 => "200"
  3 => "100"
]
```

here's the condition I am trying to fix

```
    //update the status of the order
    if(empty($input['remainingDeliveries'])) {
        $order_idAcceptedItem = $acceptItem['order_id'];
        $setStatus = \App\Orders::where('id', '=', $order_idAcceptedItem)->first();
        if ($setStatus)
        {
            $setStatus->status_id = 3;
        }      
        $setStatus->save();
```

The `$input['remainingDeliveries']` carrying the array.

```
    } else {
        $order_idAcceptedItem = $acceptItem['order_id'];
        $setStatus = \App\Orders::where('id', '=', $order_idAcceptedItem)->first();
        if ($setStatus)
        {
            $setStatus->status_id = 4;
        }      
        $setStatus->save();
    }
```

at first, I thought my condition is ok but when I try to create a record with this array value,

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "152"
  1 => "0"
  2 => "0"
  3 => "0"
]
```

it triggers the **ELSE**

what is the proper way to do it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
// Filter. The $result array will be empty if all values equal "0".
$result = array_filter($inputArray, function($item) {
    // This should return a boolean value. True means discard, false means keep.
    return $item === '0';
});
```

```
if(!count($result)) {
  // all empty thus everything was "0".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Laravel's Collection class to check the array:

```
if( collect($input['remainingDeliveries'])->every(function($value, $key){
    return $value == '0';
}) ) {
    // they are all '0'
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-every

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error? Or is it not correctly detecting non-zero items in your array?